# VS 2019. Internal Web Browser as default browser in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I use Browse with -> Internal Web Browser -> Set as Default -> Browse.
Its ok, project have running in IDE. But when I pressing ctrl+F5 it running in separate window in Internet Expolorer.
How to set the Internal Web Browser as default when pressing ctrl+F5 in IDE?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a shortcut dedicated to running a project with a Internal Web Browser "Ctrl+Shift+W", which is different from F5 (non-debug mode running projects).
[Source (MSDN)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/1a05793a-4d70-49b7-9aa8-b0d25885f797/internal-web-browser-as-default-browser-in-debug-mode?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

PS. It works only if you're staying on the view (*.cshtml in my case)

Answer (score 1):

you need to turn off Visual Studio JavaScript Debugging. Go to Tools->Options and turn off the option Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET. then go to the project property > Web section > select "Don't open a Page"

For Further Details Refer :
https://medium.com/@airyboy/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-from-opening-a-new-browser-window-for-asp-net-mvcapplication-7ac4d6e01a17

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.
Internal Browser inside the IDE doesn't open.